# Is it possible to decrypt shadow files?

Tags: shadow, encryption

I don't know either its possible to decrypt a shadow file or not. Just want know if One can decrypt the information or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a perfect post about shadow file and the hash there :

[Decrypt Shadow File](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/program-for-decrypt-linux-shadow-file)

You will also find more informations about Rainbow Table which was mentionned by Billy Moon.

Comment: I used JTR. For one file it did immediately but for other its running for an hour now but no output.

Comment: I never used it but you can find some tutorial from Google like this one : http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=455. Can't help you more about that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can not be decrypted, as it uses one way hash, but can be cracked using rainbow table.

Comment: For example I have this one : $1$YQYVIGeC$il6OyzRbuYMasBd4/dRY00:666:0:99999:7:::

In this first part tell me its md5 and next is salt and then encrypted so what should I look in rainbow table for?